# phpexcel style not applying whole sheet

Tags: php, excel, formatting

I am creating a excel using phpexcel library on the row I am applying some style like

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A'.$row.':Q'.$row)
    ->getFont()
    ->setSize(14); ,
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A'.$row.':Q'.$row)
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
```

it is applying some top 3 to 4 pages but rest of pages this formatting is not applied kindly guide any one how i solve this problem this is very important for me.

Comment: You're applying that style to a range of cells (a specific row from column A to column Q): I'm unsure how that applies to `pages`. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Perhaps if you want this style for the entire worksheet you could apply it as a default style

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918586/phpexcel-specific-cell-formatting-from-style-object

Answer (score 0):

can u please try this?

```
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Times New Roman');
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(10);
```